# Lua data not being rendered on pongo2 template

Tags: go, lua, go-templates, pongo2

I'm using [algernon](https://github.com/xyproto/algernon) to try to output data from a lua script into a [pongo2](https://github.com/flosch/pongo2) template.

In the code below **number_list** outputs exactly as I'd expect but nothing renders for **object_list**.

What am I doing wrong?

```
title = "This is the title"

number_list = {}

table.insert(number_list, 1)
table.insert(number_list, 2)
table.insert(number_list, 3)

object_list = {}

o1 = {1}
table.insert(object_list, o1)
o2 = {2}
table.insert(object_list, o2)
o3 = {3}
table.insert(object_list, o3)
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ title }}
    <div>

        {% for item in number_list %}
        test 1: {{item}} 
        {% endfor %}

        {% for item in object_list %}
        test 2: {{item}}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

edit: Turns out it's a [bug](https://github.com/xyproto/algernon/issues/119). Check out @IdeaToCode answer or the bug report for a different way to do it.

Comment: Maybe you must iterate for item in object_list, or print `item[0]`.

Comment: That doesn't work. The text "test 2:" also isn't printed so I guess "object_list" doesn't have any length for some reason.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion you could hack your way out of this via nesting the `test:2 {{item}}` line into another for loop, which iterates over `item`

Comment: @Guilty Just tried it but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know lua but in most languages objects need to have keys.
I ran this using algernon and it appears to work as you intended.

example.lua:

```lua
title = "This is the title"

number_list = {}

table.insert(number_list, 1)
table.insert(number_list, 2)
table.insert(number_list, 3)

object_list = {}

o1 = {id = 1}
table.insert(object_list, o1)
o2 = {id = 2}
table.insert(object_list, o2)
o3 = {id = 3}
table.insert(object_list, o3)


serve2("example.html", { object_list = object_list, number_list = number_list})
```

example.html:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{ title }}
    <div>

        {% for item in number_list %}
        test 1: {{item}}<br>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for item in object_list %}
        test 2: {{item.id}}<br>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works for the **serve2** method but not the **data.lua** method. The key isn't really the problem. Even if you use just plain text inside **object_list** in **data.lua** there are no iterations. It's just been confirmed as a [bug](https://github.com/xyproto/algernon/issues/119) a few days ago. In the meantime I'll accept your answer and advise people to use the **serve2** method you have in your example.

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to the [bug page](https://github.com/xyproto/algernon/issues/119) in your answer? Thanks.